# Как разбить строку на переменные с преобразованием

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно разделить **input** на переменные нужного типа. К примеру на вход получаем **"Иван 10 100"** необходимо разделить это на **3** переменные с типами **str, int, int**. Есть решение с написанием отдельного метода, но от него требуется избавиться.

```
def participant(name, score, penalty):
    return [- int(score), int(penalty), name]
amount = int(input())
members = [participant(*input().split()) for _ in range(amount)]
```

Comment: **Уточнение** Для правильности решения задачи порядок требуется изменить, в конкретном случае первый параметр **Иван** перемещается в конец а **10**  должна принять отрицательное значение. Прошу прощения за не точность.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете проверить состоит ли строка из одних только цифр и преобразовать только эти части

```
parts = []
string = 'hello 10 world 45'
for s in string.split(' '):
    if s.isdigit():
        parts.append(int(s))
    else:
        parts.append(s)
print(parts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Построить список с помощью list comprehension

```
a = input()
result = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in a.split()]
print(result)
```